# Javafx Stage is blank for a moment

Tags: javafx-8

I have a stage which shows some data.

I have a service which loads the data and update the view.

The problem is when stage.show() is executed, the stage is blank for a while..

I tried to increase the heap size but it does not change this behaviour.

Any ideas ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Without showing any code it's always guessing arround.

The the main reason for such things is a task blocking the JFXApplication Thread which could be in your case the call of the service method which fetches data from somewhere.

You should look into the [Task docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html)
which have a lot of exampels.

As a hint you should never block the MainThread as your GUI gets unresponsable.